# No outline in VS Code Latex Workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I am an otherwise very happy user of Latex-Workshop in VS Code but lately my document outline has not been appearing for TeX files (neither in the Explorer nor in the LaTeX menu). It works for .bib files though.

I tried to open & close documents of different types in VS Code and to restart VS Code but the problem is persistent.

Any idea on how to fix this? It's an important feature.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall another older version and reload it. Everything will be fine.